# Alfresco debugger cannot open js including an import tag

Tags: javascript, share, alfresco

I'm implementing a custom document-details action in Share on **community 4.0.a**.
This action is using repository webscript that acts as an HTTP POST handler.

So I went to `/alfresco/service/api/javascript/debugger` to enable the js debugger tool.

But when I try to open a js file manually like aspects.post.json.js it launches a syntax error.

it does it with any js that starts with:

```
<import resource="classpath:/alfresco/xxx/xxx.js">
```

Is there anything I should be aware of to use this debugger with such files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "import tag" is not valid javascript. Thats why javascript syntax aware editors complain. As Florian mentions, it is resolved before the "whole" javascript is fed to the interpreter (rhino).

Nevertheless, would be nice if Alfresco would replace this tag with valid javascript to make tools happy - maybe with something similiar to the `require` function node.js provides.

Comment: yes this is a good suggestion. I like the way it's done in node

Answer (score 2):

I have opened an improvement request (or rather contribution) in the Alfresco JIRA which addresses this issue by providing a clean import API in JavaScript. In case you want to play around with it, you can grab the patch files as attachments at https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-13631

With this, your example

```
<import resource="classpath:/alfresco/xxx/xxx.js">
```

becomes

```
importScript("legacy", "classpath:/alfresco/xxx/xxx.js", true); //Repository tier
importScript("classpath:/alfresco/xxx/xxx.js", true); //Share tier
```

Comment: well actually it seems that they have modified most of their webscripts to do the imports in a separate js file, so it's no longer an issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have never tried it but I am pretty sure that the debugger can't handle the  statements. The debugger comes from the Rhino javascript engine and the import tags are an extension from Alfresco. They are resolved before the script is actually run in the Javascript engine.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, try to separate the actual javascript code into different .js files as described here: [Alfresco Web Scripts using Javascript – Part 1](http://www.devswede.com/2015/03/alfresco-web-scripts-using-javascript-part-1/).

> The first challenge when structuring your Web script code is how
>   Alfresco imports additional Javascript files. Alfresco expects
>   xml-style  tags at the top of the main Web
>   script file. This will break javascript validation, automatic code
>   indentation and other important editor features.
>
> This can be solved by placing all Javascript code in separate files,
>   leaving only the import declarations in the main Web script .js file.

Of course, this only works if you got full control over the webscript files..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please quote the most relevant part of the link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).